# Python well-formed XML file, up to specific tag only

Tags: python, xml-parsing, lxml

I have a file, which is NOT xml, but it contains xml up to specific tag, AND I have to parse from beginning tag up to specific final tag. AND I get always error if I open the file normal way (except for 'rb', which is in my humble opinion not viable).

If I run:

```
parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
tree = ET.parse(filepath, parser=parser)
```

I get error:

```
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21688\1899539113.py in <module>
      1 parser = ET.XMLParser(recover=True)
----> 2 tree = ET.parse(path, parser=parser)

src\lxml\etree.pyx in lxml.etree.parse()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseDocument()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._handleParseResult()

src\lxml\parser.pxi in lxml.etree._raiseParseError()

OSError: Error reading file
```

but I know that I can parse it up to a specific tag.

So I would like to know whether or not it is possible to restrict the 'parse' up to certain tag.

[image]

Thanks a lot.
Davide

Comment: I understand that this is a no-no with an XML, but since it's not and you are looking for a specific tag (or a set of specific tags) you can use regEx to retrieve the values paired with the tags, is there a reason you avoid regular expressions?

Comment: I have to parse from beginning tag up to specific final tag. Not only 1 tag. And I get always error if I open the file normal way (except for 'rb')

Comment: If the tag has a rule, you can parse multiple tags with regEx, e.g.: `((?<Start><(.*)>)(?<Content>.*)(?<End><\/(.*)>))` parses the start tag, the content and the end tag of a Regular non-multiline XML file and creates 3 named groups to read easily etween them :)

Comment: Can you show us the file contents? Currently it is unclear how to reproduce the error. The fact that you get an OSError seems to indicate something else than a parsing problem.

Comment: and yes, as far as I cannot do incremental parsing I get I/O error I guess